# request.getCookies() throws NullPointerException although the request is not null

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, nullpointerexception, session-cookies

I've the following `utility` function to get value from `cookie`:

```
public static long getClientTimezoneOffset(HttpServletRequest request) 
{
        long timeZoneOffset = 0;
        if(request != null)
        {
            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies(); // throws null pointer exeception from here

            if(cookies != null) 
            {
                for(Cookie cookie : cookies) 
                {
                    if(cookie.getName().equals("timezoneOffset")) 
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            timeZoneOffset = Long.parseLong(cookie.getValue());
                        } 
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return timeZoneOffset;
}
```

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseCookies(Request.java:2943)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.convertCookies(Request.java:2958)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getCookies(Request.java:1987)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getCookies(RequestFacade.java:662)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getCookies(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:69)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getCookies(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:69)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getCookies(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:69)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getCookies(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:69)
> ```

I've checked the `request` object and it's not `NULL`. It's not always throwing **exception** but sometimes. That's why it's getting difficult to figure out the actual problem.

I've already checked the similar posts regarding this but none of this helped. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"It's not always throwing exception but sometimes"* it sounds strange for me. Does NPE have any message?

Comment: Pardon me. What's this acronym `NPE` used for? @AndrewTobilko

Comment: I've posted a portion of the full stacktrace. Should I post the full?

Comment: I think, in this case, you need

Comment: What version of Tomcat?  The version you are using is necessary to track the exact source line.  But looking at the source I'm using, parseCookies would NPE (null pointer exception) if the request doesn't have a context or couldn't get a cookieProcessor object.  Neither of those should happen if this is a normal request.  Are you sending the exact and unmodified request object received from Tomcat to getClientTimezoneOffset()?  Post some code from com.revechat.user.login.LoginDAO.isValidUser()

Comment: tomcat version 8.0. Yes I am sending the exact same request. @MarkOlsson

Comment: 8.0.what?  The last number is important.

Comment: `apache-tomcat-8.0.18` @MarkOlsson

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with the application storing a reference to an `HttpServletRequest` for longer than the request is valid. I'd recommend that you (a) upgrade to 8.0.latest and (b) fix your app.

Comment: I've upgraded to `tomcat 8.0.36` may be it's latest for the time being and couldn't reproduce the issue. @ChristopherSchultz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed in version 8.029.  See this bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58578

Your version of Tomcat is pretty old, probably time to update anyway.  If that's not possible, look at checking for `request.getContext() == null` before calling `request.getCookies()`.  It would probably occur only when there is some problem during host mapping, but without lots more info I couldn't tell you the exact cause.  With some extra logging you might be able to compare the details of a good request to a bad one and see where the difference is.

**EDIT:**

*Upgrading to <kbd>`tomcat 8.0.36`</kbd> resolved the issue.*

Comment: also getting the same exception. `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getServletContext(Request.java:1593)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getContextPath(Request.java:1910)`

Comment: Use `((Request)request).getContext()` instead, that one can't NPE.

Comment: There's no such function `request.getContext()`. When I type that `request.getContextPath()` appears. By the way, I've upgraded to `tomcat 8.0.36` and couldn't reproduce the issue. I will let you know after being confirmed that the issue's gone.

Comment: By the way, I faced this problem in this version of tomcat too `apache-tomcat-7.0.68`. @MarkOlsson

Comment: That's why the cast to Request - `((Request)request).getContext()`.  There's no getContext() in an HttpServletRequest, because you're only seeing the interface methods.  If you cast your `request` (lower case r) to a `Request` object, which is what it actually is (in Tomcat at least), you gain access to other methods like getContext().  But all that is moot, since the update fixed the problem and you don't need to do that anyway.

Comment: I've edited your answer. I've stated there what actually worked for me. Thanks for your time. I really appreciate this.